# Write a query in SQL to find the name of the patients who taken an advanced appointment, and also display their physicians and medication

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBl1j.png)

I need to select the patients who have done a advance appointment meaning patients having same patient id and multiple start_dt , I can get all the info but then i have to use the group by function but i also have to display the other columns like physician name and medication , how can i approach this problem

I can get the info using left outer joins but what I want to know is that is there a way where i can display multiple columns of different tables while also being able to use group by function .
thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service; **YOU** need to attempt the question (and show your attempt) and then we can help with debugging. Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; a complete description of the problem you are trying to solve; and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want values from all the matching rows and columns then you can use an analytic function (rather than an aggregation function).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT start_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY patient) AS num_starts
  FROM   hr.appointment a
)
WHERE  num_starts > 1
```

Will get all the appointments for each patient where that patient has multiple start dates.

You have not shared any sample data or expected output so this is just to demonstrate the technique you can use to find all the rows and columns where there are multiple matches within the group.

Answer (score 0):

Partial multiple tables data - just as a sample to work with:

```sql
WITH
    patients AS
        (   Select 'P_001' "PATIENT_ID", 'Jane' "PATIENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P_002' "PATIENT_ID", 'Robert' "PATIENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P_003' "PATIENT_ID", 'Mick' "PATIENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P_004' "PATIENT_ID", 'Alice' "PATIENT_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P_005' "PATIENT_ID", 'John' "PATIENT_NAME" From Dual 
        ),
    physicians AS
        (   Select 1 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'Patric' "PHYSICIAN_NAME", 'Surgery' "DEPARTMENT" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'Maria' "PHYSICIAN_NAME", 'Neurology' "DEPARTMENT" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'Paul' "PHYSICIAN_NAME", 'Surgery' "DEPARTMENT" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'Joan' "PHYSICIAN_NAME", 'ORL' "DEPARTMENT" From Dual 
        ),
    apps AS
        (   Select 'P_001' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('12.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 4 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_002' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('14.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 1 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_003' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('21.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 2 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_004' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('28.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 4 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_003' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 2 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_002' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('04.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 3 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual Union All
          Select 'P_005' "PATIENT_ID", To_Date('07.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "APP_START_DATE", 1 "PHYSICIAN_ID", 'some medication info' "MEDICATION" From Dual 
        )
```

Main SQL

```
Select a.PATIENT_ID, p.PATIENT_NAME, a.APP_START_DATE, a.PHYSICIAN_ID, ph.PHYSICIAN_NAME, ph.DEPARTMENT, a.MEDICATION
From apps a
Inner Join patients p ON(p.PATIENT_ID = a.PATIENT_ID)
Inner Join physicians ph ON(ph.PHYSICIAN_ID = a.PHYSICIAN_ID)
Where a.PATIENT_ID IN (Select PATIENT_ID From apps Group By PATIENT_ID HAVING(Count(*) > 1))   -- subquery with Group By and HAVING clause as filter
Order By a.PATIENT_ID, a.APP_START_DATE
```

Result:

```sql
PATIENT_ID PATIENT_NAME APP_START_DATE PHYSICIAN_ID PHYSICIAN_NAME DEPARTMENT MEDICATION         
---------- ------------ -------------- ------------ -------------- ---------- --------------------
P_002      Robert       14-FEB-23                 1 Patric         Surgery    some medication info 
P_002      Robert       04-MAR-23                 3 Paul           Surgery    some medication info 
P_003      Mick         21-FEB-23                 2 Maria          Neurology  some medication info 
P_003      Mick         01-MAR-23                 2 Maria          Neurology  some medication info
```